# Servlet in Java. How to retrieve attributes?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, session-variables

I am really struggling with this problem. I am storing names and addresses of users as session variables on the server. In the `else if` statement, I want to search through previously entered names to match a name that is entered (with the address field blank), to the corresponding address that was entered for that name.

```
For example:
First entered details: Name=John, Address=Ireland,
Second entered details: Name=Mary, Address=France,
Third entered details: Name=John, Address=null,(EMPTY FIELD)
```

When these third details are entered for 'John', I want to retrieve the address for John (ie:Ireland) that was previously entered for that user. Can't figure out why it won't work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
@WebServlet("/Test2") // tells server under which URL to offer this servlet
public class UserRegistration extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        // set content-type header before accessing the Writer
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        // then write the response
        out.println("<html>" + "<head><title>Online Shopping Directory</title></head>");
        //Get the identifier of the book to display
        out.println("<body bgcolor=\"#ffffff\">"
                + "<h2>Please enter your name:</h2>" + "<form method=\"get\">"
                + "<input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" size=\"25\">"
                + "<p></p>"
                + "<h2>Please enter your address:</h2>" + "<form method=\"get\">"
                + "<input type=\"text\" name=\"useraddress\" size=\"25\">"
                + "<p></p>"
                + "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\">"
                + "<input type=\"reset\" value=\"Reset\">"
                + "</form>");

        String name = request.getParameter("username");
        String address = request.getParameter("useraddress");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        if ((name != null) && (name.length() > 0) && (address != null) && (address.length() > 0)) {

            session.setAttribute("username", address);
            out.println("The username " + name + " has been saved for "
                    + "this session. The address of this user is "
                    + (String) session.getAttribute("username"));
        } else if ((name.equals("username")) && (address == null)) {
            out.println("The username " + name + " is already saved. "
                    + "The address of this user is "
                    + (String) session.getAttribute("username"));
        }
        out.println("</body></html>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is you goal a suggestion box?

Comment: I'm new to programming and am just looking for a bit of help with a problem that I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out myself. If that help is in the form of 'suggestions' like you said, that's fine with me but if you don't want to help that's fine with me too.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I meant the method to display the previously entered data in conjunction with the entered information.

Comment: Try `request.getSession(false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to do something like the following :

```
 if ((name != null) && (name.length() > 0) ){

 session.setAttribute("username", name);

out.println("The username " + name  );


}else {
out.println("The username " + (String) session.getAttribute("username") );
}





if ((address != null) && (address.length() > 0)){
session.setAttribute("address", address);

  out.println("The address " + adress );

}else {
out.println("The address " + (String) session.getAttribute("address") );
}
```

and please give me some feedback .

Hope That helps .

Comment: Thanks for your help. That helped me out a lot and sorry for being so slow to acknowledge the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list to pop up, if the user enters a certain prefix to an already entered text, you have to store text first. Use a list object to add the information when it is submitted to the server and store it in the user's session. Keep in mind, that when the session times out or is removed, your list will not longer be available. To store the list of entered information in a more persistent manner, you could use a database instead.

When the user requests the page, where the information should be entered, you retrieve the list from her session and write it to the page (look for auto suggestion box to find out, how to do it using javascript).

Answer (score 0):

You are actually  creating a new session instance evertime, you should get the session instance associated with the request while you need to retrieve the attributes

Use `request.getSession(false);` this will return the associated session with the request or return null. you should be careful in handling sessions while managing sessions, that is when to create a new one or retrieve the session that had been created for the user